# ExpectationNotMetError, method returns nil

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I am doing an online exercise. I am asked to create an `InterestCalculator` class that takes four arguments on initialization and defines two functions, `amount` and `statement`. I have to use the `self` method throughout the class. Instance variables should only be directly accessed in the `initialize` function and `amount` should only be calculated in one place.

Here are the specs:

```
describe InterestCalculator do
  before { @calc = InterestCalculator.new(500, 0.05, 4, 5) }

  describe "#amount" do
    it "calculates correctly" do
      expect( @calc.amount ).to eq(610.1)
    end
  end

  describe "#statement" do
    it "calls amount" do
      @calc.stub(:amount).and_return(100)
      expect( @calc.statement ).to eq("After 4 years I'll have 100 dollars!")
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my code:

```
class InterestCalculator
  attr_accessor :amount, :statement

  def initialize(principal, rate, years, times_compounded)
    @principal = principal
    @rate = rate
    @years = years
    @times_compounded = times_compounded
  end
  def self.amount
    amount = principal * (1 + rate / times_compounded) ** (times_compounded * years)
  end
  def self.statement
    statement = "After #{years} years i'll have #{amount} dollars"
  end
end
```

I keep getting the following error and don't know why:

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError

expected: 610.1
     got: nil

RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError

expected: "After 4 years I'll have 100 dollars!"
     got: nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend `amount` and `statement` to be instance methods then change your code to

```
def amount
  @amount ||= @principal * (1 + @rate / @times_compounded) ** (@times_compounded * @years)
end

def statement
  @statement ||= "After #{@years} years i'll have #{amount} dollars"
end
```

this is because

```
def self.my_method
  # method body
end
```

creates a class method.  Also, if you want `amount` and `statement` to be read-only change `attr_accessor` to `attr_reader`.

Comment: The following line cannot be changed:

amount = principal * (1 + rate / times_compounded) ** (times_compounded * years)

I just have to put together the class and methods to make it work.

Comment: In that case, you can make accessors for `principal`, `rate`, `times_compounded`, and `years`.

Answer (score -1):

Made it work like this:

```
class InterestCalculator
  attr_accessor :amount, :statement, :years

  def initialize(principal, rate, years, times_compounded)
    @principal = principal
    @rate = rate
    @years = years
    @times_compounded = times_compounded
    self.amount = principal * (1 + rate / times_compounded) ** (times_compounded * years)
    self.amount = amount.round(1)
  end

  def statement
    statement = "After #{years} years I'll have #{amount} dollars!"
  end

end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if you know this but you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks JCM, I will be able to do so in 2 days!

Comment: This works - but it's really bad practice to do calculations in an initializer. Internalizer needs to SETUP (prepare for further use) an instance of the class, NOT do calculations that change it's initial state.